# ASP.NET MVC Razor Multi select listbox as a checkbox

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checkedlistbox

Is this really not built-in yet? Do I have to download and install some plugin to accomplish this?

If so - what are your favorite ones to implement a listbox that uses checkboxes?

I feel like there should be a "type" property and checkbox be an option on the HTML ListBoxFor!

Answer (score 1):

These are installable with nuget

- https://github.com/mikhail-tsennykh/MvcCheckBoxList
- http://benfoster.io/blog/checkbox-lists-in-aspnet-mvc

I think the 2nd one has nicer syntax, but jquery validation doesn't work on it anymore.

Comment: Those are nice but I don't see why it isn't just part of MVC to begin with. I shouldn't have to download anything.